# IOS App Submission with Encryption / Fairplay, how to do or automatic

Tags: ios, encryption, submission, fairplay

Looking around a bit just need a quick overview on one how the application itself is encrypted   or not.

By default while building the app, it is all un-encrypted when loaded on the test devices, etc.

So when we go to submit the app and build it for distribution, when does it get encrypted so when it is deployed on the user's phone it is not easily reverse engineered....

Or is this an additional step that has to happen at build / submission time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but since others will ask the same question eventually - You don't have to do anything because when you build the .ipa file it is already encrypted using FairPlay, as indicated in the info.plist. To confirm this, use the utility "otool" like so from the command line:

```
otool -arch armv7 -l YourAppName | grep crypt
```

Comment: is this true for enterprise applications that are signed with an apple enterprise certificate and not distributed outside the appstore?